# Writing output to a text file using Hadoop Grip command

Tags: hadoop, grep, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a file in HDFS - /user//SimpleDir/SimpleFile.txt and I'm trying to use Grep command and search for "MapReduce" in that file and print the results to a different file (simpleoutput.txt) in the same directory.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command

hadoop fs -cat /user/SimpleDir/SimpleFile.txt | grep -i Mapreduce > /user/SimpleDir/simpleoutput.txt

Comment: seems like a working command, but I'm getting this error 
``"cat: Unable to write to output stream."``

Comment: Is this an error or a warning? Can you try just the grep part alone? If the resultant is too large you might get this error

Comment: Ideally then it should have appended that output to the file also. Maybe try >> instead of > just after the grep command

Comment: >> didn't work.

Comment: ideally it should have written the output to a file. You are using all this in linux right? then its weird that it aint working for you

Comment: I'm on Windows - Maybe it's writing to part-r-0000? I'm not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241887/discussion-between-lazydeveloper-and-varadharajan-raghavendran).

Comment: Its the same problem with linux also (mac)